# Is there a way to make this R for loop work

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I'm looking for an easy way to loop through my data and print out certain columns based on a condition.
This for-loop ought to find the column within the data that meets the if condition and then print out these columns. This is what I have tried.

```
for (var in names(df)) {
    if(length (unique(df[var])) == 2) {
       print (var)
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use doublebrackets:

```
for (var in names(df)) {
  if(length (unique(df[[var]])) == 2) {
    print(var)
  }
}
```

This is a bit tricky. But `R` stores data.frames internally as a list and the single bracket indexing gives a data.frame with 1 column. And applyiing `length` to a data.frame returns its number of columns.
A more functional approach would be

```
uniqueElementCount <- vapply(X = df,FUN = function(columnValues) {length(unique(columnValues))}, FUN.VALUE = double(1))
names(df)[uniqueElementCount  == 2]
```

Comment: Hey thanks Jonas, forgot above the double brackets, this worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an `apply` function here for a vectorized solution:

```r
idx <- sapply(names(df), function(x) length(unique(df[, x])) == 2)
names(df)[idx]
```

The `idx` vector will be assigned a boolean T/F depending on whether each particular column in the data frame match the length/unique check.  Then, we can simply subset the original names of the data frame using this boolean vector to see all matching column names.

Answer (score 0):

In R you should avoid using "for" loops, in big datasets loops are slow.
Consider using lapply:

```
columns <- lapply(df, function(var) {
  length(unique(var)) == 2
})
```

Anyway, the problem with your code is that you are not trying to subset df on the columns, you could just substitute `df[var]` with `df[, var]`

Comment: Just discovered this - lappy/Sappy function,  but thanks for advice